# Is any good way to ask and answer about vega / vega-lite?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

By good questions and answers I mean:

- example data
- chart definition
- visible output

I copied example from `vega-embed` into `snippet`, but it a bit bigger in `html` part than I expected.

Click Run to see a char and you can edit it with *edit the above snippet* link.

```js
var yourVlSpec = {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.0.json",
      "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"a": "A","b": 28}, {"a": "B","b": 55}, {"a": "C","b": 43},
          {"a": "D","b": 91}, {"a": "E","b": 81}, {"a": "F","b": 53},
          {"a": "G","b": 19}, {"a": "H","b": 87}, {"a": "I","b": 52}
        ]
      },
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal"},
        "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
vegaEmbed("#vis", yourVlSpec,{actions:{export: false, source: false}});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@3">
</script>

<body>
  <div id="vis"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сurrent vega editor allows users to share charts ([example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-QEdAASVX2AQA7rjfi83h0AI6scVGGJGKhLJ27Lr4gNiNGmACyjEOsAA+m9dCWAOLoMRiU6UmPvKAJpPMaKMNNmpFuuv3P0GqBuyHMYz4-aHY6j0zgu6-HN5qAAeX0TBUDdeTcgSm40pr6YHkAoNdYm+oumQnUgApNho0BX75pK4oqVRqIP9Rc5ffi46OJxlYI3LOeQrBmFq6Napi2vajqIpALpuh6EpekivofoGpghs4XLcJGWzrrGpgtsEbapu0XbmpecR-ACuYdIWxZlriVY1nWa5QI28aJiRKYduRGZFD2VTZrRC6QMung0gRm7bruyQUZmnwAF5NvER5iCevIAAxaTeYAmisID6kAA)) - so that might be the best way to communicate issues/solutions on stackoverflow.